# PHP cURL script works on one system, fails on another, but can't identify the difference

Tags: php, curl

I have some code which validates that a non-profit is in good standing with the IRS by looking up the organization's Employer Identification Number (EIN) on the IRS website's Tax-Exempt Organization Search page using page scraping via PHP cURL. Recently it began to fail with 403/Forbidden errors. I re-wrote it to adapt to changes on the IRS website. Now I have code that works as expected on my development system(s) while the identical code (verified with "sum" on the two files involved) fails with a 403 error on our production system, but I'm stuck on identifying the difference causing the problem.

I have two systems on which the code works: Fedora 35 Linux, with PHP 8.0.18 and cURL 7.79.1 and Fedora 36 Linux with PHP 8.1.6 and cURL 7.82.0. The production system hosted at HostGator is CentOS with PHP 7.4.29 and cURL 7.83.1, so older PHP with newer cURL.

The code first performs a GET on the search page to load the cookies and collect the form field default values then a POST to submit the form with the EIN in the right form field. The Fedora systems get the expected 302 response to the POST while the CentOS system gets a 403 response.

For debugging, I've tried constraining the obvious variations between the systems by forcing the use of IPv4 and HTTP/2 and re-run the tests until both are captured using the same IP address for the load-balanced website. Unfortunately I can't capture packets on the production system at the hosting company to look for differences in the interaction with the website. I'm hoping a cURL wizard may be able to spot a key difference from the two verbose output captures (with my cURL option dumps) below.

**Working (PHP 8.1.6, cURL 7.82.0):**

```
* Connection #0 to host apps.irs.gov left intact
=> POST options: Array
(
    [19913] => 1
    [52] => 1
    [10023] => Array
        (
            [0] => User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/64.0.3282.140 Safari/537.36 Edge/18.17763
            [1] => Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
        )

    [10031] => 
    [113] => 1
    [84] => 3
    [41] => 1
    [47] => 1
    [10015] => einTerm=01-0211671&orgTerm=&resultsPerPage=25&indexOfFirstRow=0&dispatchMethod=searchAll&city=&fromDate=&toDate=&sortColumn=orgName&isDescending=false&searchType=allSearch&searchBy=EIN&state=All+States&country=All+Countries&exemptionType=al&deductibilityCode=all
    [10002] => https://apps.irs.gov/app/eos/search;jsessionid=XTl16dGwQzYJg5v12y9oRVKE.20
)
* Found bundle for host apps.irs.gov: 0x564a9448dcc0 [can multiplex]
* Re-using existing connection! (#0) with host apps.irs.gov
* Connected to apps.irs.gov (23.63.32.192) port 443 (#0)
* h2h3 [:method: POST]
* h2h3 [:path: /app/eos/search;jsessionid=XTl16dGwQzYJg5v12y9oRVKE.20]
* h2h3 [:scheme: https]
* h2h3 [:authority: apps.irs.gov]
* h2h3 [accept: */*]
* h2h3 [cookie: JSESSIONID=XTl16dGwQzYJg5v12y9oRVKE.20; AWSALBCORS=hQQX7Xg5jDR+DCyEijfM4m6EsSevyrr3mZPmycLLOb2LwlJ58P8CSB9EIEl0JK2Vhr7YhPTn3VCuqcbmOMmnjed/M9qqvCkTygzaNT4H1IQefAHd5yjsXNVi7kb+; AWSALB=hQQX7Xg5jDR+DCyEijfM4m6EsSevyrr3mZPmycLLOb2LwlJ58P8CSB9EIEl0JK2Vhr7YhPTn3VCuqcbmOMmnjed/M9qqvCkTygzaNT4H1IQefAHd5yjsXNVi7kb+; ak_bmsc=8A537191012B749495893F1E10E74180~000000000000000000000000000000~YAAQPvffF1ihS9yAAQAAlaU19w/wPEliSNxMTXTsIyeT0I4D+idIAOo56QuNPDRd2bP/dTC9VU886WqlmkqXr0QwUkGQYZzpfAPIc4BEGNRixowHExzoLMYGMG9ta787mTsmOIFHTBqi3zXqkAkj1ScvE3ci9UgDMkXtEVi9sarHlLaquGMNfP9tPFkewTm0OlGZbVYyELuX2yx510QYEt03fif2MIZXz/CUMLtNPivoLMfTq1npNuJae7HGi3IEAQ64jchcxrV0oaVmSVCCV8Nj9Br0AqS/zknVE6MZETfKcdj9cFsBGEwlaiaDf1nZSMYnPCtTX2AGpHo2v6wW+keT0omBqEJM8S4TUwPONYx0nJe5i6nbqMjybxPgenErrcllS+L2; bm_sz=3B45C20CE8274677307CCA048B47E083~YAAQPvffF1ehS9yAAQAAQ6U19w/soNdV6oojiKE0rlk1RAJpAIt61GrHJAc0PN/xaRq3ZIS1XW9ZquKP4QMBY8P4UIu2/W8r3uzPRfe9/9uvSmjfWRAELmtVKY7qTQ0tRgc6s3Gs7h1ZTO7/e3VuEoqtmp8Pm/gmEMEtqkPoDtMevcqg1+8I/pXczASW8V7YbQtpmww1r81hZSrNKQMSlcfikCES/lobe1Q7w8NH7RQMkgVzZY246ULcYc3qtC2DE9mIKhg+VklSqCv0zFlV6FFdW9E5cuZTpUs1MWw4eLE=~4470852~4273716; _abck=1676C85BF3ECBCF69975274117E26FBE~-1~YAAQPvffF1ahS9yAAQAAQ6U19wdgZ0p23LgMfm0QsDeAJI8RD/YAPQe366g5hGIe1klI/ZpE5q7vrOX0YxletWFVqUl9jaSokNX4er6uAeVjdJ1MEG/Sra6MhmJOPW6NPGWhn7dx1DZt1W1KvShd4LHknAILAfaIY1NhY/SVqOrt1SYmlAvQNw+yPxnWzPsHB9t3/y6TTFQfvREisQscoG4uqA6aV9ZKN953qMtLUkxc34mz+jNFGIwexn+8Dc6glGY5mVQPv95YFUO87ogIfMY2V+iDCxhNlh22QNx0O2QEHxrW+lLByRza/Nt5awaPGQtqzsnTf8J9JePL9fahS2e4995pgxTpHrGRxIQ5LljTpxD1H1yEVep3~-1~-1~-1]
* h2h3 [user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/64.0.3282.140 Safari/537.36 Edge/18.17763]
* h2h3 [accept-language: en-US,en;q=0.5]
* h2h3 [content-length: 262]
* h2h3 [content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded]
* Using Stream ID: 5 (easy handle 0x564a94489610)
> POST /app/eos/search;jsessionid=XTl16dGwQzYJg5v12y9oRVKE.20 HTTP/2
Host: apps.irs.gov
accept: */*
cookie: JSESSIONID=XTl16dGwQzYJg5v12y9oRVKE.20; AWSALBCORS=hQQX7Xg5jDR+DCyEijfM4m6EsSevyrr3mZPmycLLOb2LwlJ58P8CSB9EIEl0JK2Vhr7YhPTn3VCuqcbmOMmnjed/M9qqvCkTygzaNT4H1IQefAHd5yjsXNVi7kb+; AWSALB=hQQX7Xg5jDR+DCyEijfM4m6EsSevyrr3mZPmycLLOb2LwlJ58P8CSB9EIEl0JK2Vhr7YhPTn3VCuqcbmOMmnjed/M9qqvCkTygzaNT4H1IQefAHd5yjsXNVi7kb+; ak_bmsc=8A537191012B749495893F1E10E74180~000000000000000000000000000000~YAAQPvffF1ihS9yAAQAAlaU19w/wPEliSNxMTXTsIyeT0I4D+idIAOo56QuNPDRd2bP/dTC9VU886WqlmkqXr0QwUkGQYZzpfAPIc4BEGNRixowHExzoLMYGMG9ta787mTsmOIFHTBqi3zXqkAkj1ScvE3ci9UgDMkXtEVi9sarHlLaquGMNfP9tPFkewTm0OlGZbVYyELuX2yx510QYEt03fif2MIZXz/CUMLtNPivoLMfTq1npNuJae7HGi3IEAQ64jchcxrV0oaVmSVCCV8Nj9Br0AqS/zknVE6MZETfKcdj9cFsBGEwlaiaDf1nZSMYnPCtTX2AGpHo2v6wW+keT0omBqEJM8S4TUwPONYx0nJe5i6nbqMjybxPgenErrcllS+L2; bm_sz=3B45C20CE8274677307CCA048B47E083~YAAQPvffF1ehS9yAAQAAQ6U19w/soNdV6oojiKE0rlk1RAJpAIt61GrHJAc0PN/xaRq3ZIS1XW9ZquKP4QMBY8P4UIu2/W8r3uzPRfe9/9uvSmjfWRAELmtVKY7qTQ0tRgc6s3Gs7h1ZTO7/e3VuEoqtmp8Pm/gmEMEtqkPoDtMevcqg1+8I/pXczASW8V7YbQtpmww1r81hZSrNKQMSlcfikCES/lobe1Q7w8NH7RQMkgVzZY246ULcYc3qtC2DE9mIKhg+VklSqCv0zFlV6FFdW9E5cuZTpUs1MWw4eLE=~4470852~4273716; _abck=1676C85BF3ECBCF69975274117E26FBE~-1~YAAQPvffF1ahS9yAAQAAQ6U19wdgZ0p23LgMfm0QsDeAJI8RD/YAPQe366g5hGIe1klI/ZpE5q7vrOX0YxletWFVqUl9jaSokNX4er6uAeVjdJ1MEG/Sra6MhmJOPW6NPGWhn7dx1DZt1W1KvShd4LHknAILAfaIY1NhY/SVqOrt1SYmlAvQNw+yPxnWzPsHB9t3/y6TTFQfvREisQscoG4uqA6aV9ZKN953qMtLUkxc34mz+jNFGIwexn+8Dc6glGY5mVQPv95YFUO87ogIfMY2V+iDCxhNlh22QNx0O2QEHxrW+lLByRza/Nt5awaPGQtqzsnTf8J9JePL9fahS2e4995pgxTpHrGRxIQ5LljTpxD1H1yEVep3~-1~-1~-1
user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/64.0.3282.140 Safari/537.36 Edge/18.17763
accept-language: en-US,en;q=0.5
content-length: 262
content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

* We are completely uploaded and fine
< HTTP/2 302 
< content-length: 0
< x-content-type-options: nosniff
< x-xss-protection: 1; mode=block
< x-frame-options: SAMEORIGIN
< cache-control: no-store
< content-language: en-US
< location: https://apps.irs.gov/app/eos/allSearch
< date: Tue, 24 May 2022 17:55:29 GMT
```

**Failing (PHP 7.4.28, cURL 7.83.1):**

```
* Connection #0 to host apps.irs.gov left intact
=> POST options: Array
(
    [19913] => 1
    [52] => 1
    [10023] => Array
        (
            [0] => User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/64.0.3282.140 Safari/537.36 Edge/18.17763
            [1] => Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
        )

    [10031] => 
    [113] => 1
    [41] => 1
    [47] => 1
    [10015] => einTerm=01-0211671&orgTerm=&resultsPerPage=25&indexOfFirstRow=0&dispatchMethod=searchAll&city=&fromDate=&toDate=&sortColumn=orgName&isDescending=false&searchType=allSearch&searchBy=EIN&state=All+States&country=All+Countries&exemptionType=al&deductibilityCode=all
    [10002] => https://apps.irs.gov/app/eos/search;jsessionid=hFYDovqSpPQ9unggYELKowMo.21
)
* Found bundle for host: 0x2952cc0 [can multiplex]
* Re-using existing connection #0 with host apps.irs.gov
* Connected to apps.irs.gov (23.63.32.192) port 443 (#0)
* h2h3 [:method: POST]
* h2h3 [:path: /app/eos/search;jsessionid=hFYDovqSpPQ9unggYELKowMo.21]
* h2h3 [:scheme: https]
* h2h3 [:authority: apps.irs.gov]
* h2h3 [accept: */*]
* h2h3 [cookie: JSESSIONID=hFYDovqSpPQ9unggYELKowMo.21; AWSALBCORS=53A7kbQtYAwW146QYR8asR3SdVn+X7GnECF27cV7LWrC6MEeeAluAo75yZtV6woDy6eJZY0Pn46tZqMMDD2hMlRwaT3Qouuu732Ds2n6s05oILuF4g0yuT1nQOZm; AWSALB=53A7kbQtYAwW146QYR8asR3SdVn+X7GnECF27cV7LWrC6MEeeAluAo75yZtV6woDy6eJZY0Pn46tZqMMDD2hMlRwaT3Qouuu732Ds2n6s05oILuF4g0yuT1nQOZm; ak_bmsc=F7644E5B2E56D5CEC9F9214427EB9974~000000000000000000000000000000~YAAQscM9F2GW4+OAAQAANyj78Q8vLFcckNUD0HpQL3ss6AowiPbRaFmid6iQfoj2VxAeSh/Qr6dNAGezumxbeEwNazFGWBgcYSs6QWeLXTW0IrBS/QWB5ZjpcsMHpVWP7mUH9Vxaq9F6k2JEAN6HyI7aRh1dtaxvNpFmdLGZIVEv0hK8eATTHeNAfTXjz2Gw7c0Ha0BQymd+LD0y7t3NR1wgq0vCu2lWjSYmJ8dLaiW8W3nkeZZxmWKrqQI0OUUKdApQIb1Sag0dsa9qvjfaHcQD2TbrVa76b6Ik7Qk5CQqZDIy/Olo0e45RQylLZXFIxKtWNRN29eM9eNWMcwBdcZ7Q5HgjLMcPEN5WXX8fzYfX4numSMPvDBk+tYS4m3w4rI02HNshjzl4; bm_sz=9B5A183873D9DA7C215F809E880759BE~YAAQscM9F1+W4+OAAQAAsCf78Q/Ng8FzoK+miI/aUvOjaHCHXBGNMhzxx+mfJ8TGPpLyCpaMInVzbUC4GWvCbONhhUqi6fndklKkuuzwADI4kR00c9t1PvQ8V8aA0AKyR8HNfMVMfIs5IuZVdPrw3ZYGDwK5WTykEQgvRafI0xVu/x12vCigOn2+4hMvhJaurXqeBfChnC3RvQiowQy+513BMncaIXgOYsZSuWf4+jgXrAgNEY6Wc2xfBKnHifxycbgVGKgdR+3636bK2wqNRGI4e8WYL+f1ArF48LgMOsQ=~3753527~4404275; _abck=69E0B24E2773CAD514F0180403F5F6A5~-1~YAAQscM9F16W4+OAAQAAsCf78QfvL3BASG5oiS90B4saRsXqnuJNdVzBb/ET/W9XsNJ+6bjHRek2i4SGmzuLG/ZASwyjFYIdCxQiEqOelIFq/N/1jfa9xwgKHPFY7nAgdWuTeawZnlt4ZSOiJiTsRRxNY95vE5cfFzXlQiVigU5E8RYu55DL/fj7t+vLMOKu4DMUtVblmep6xSffeKcxTu1cZqKsrTazZWCJQNimbxOVUuqSvCH3iTgSbuKRY+Z8f9d9tsdOX3UHHfCUoNIIGPVsAAan/c9CPKlaqCbARtLJQJxlci2QmQvz4C1m0q7P7lPO1GIVlwolKYSwOe1EdY/sGHF/tp2N/KmFurCdCK4Jko+kvQTj2lmS~-1~-1~-1]
* h2h3 [user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/64.0.3282.140 Safari/537.36 Edge/18.17763]
* h2h3 [accept-language: en-US,en;q=0.5]
* h2h3 [content-length: 262]
* h2h3 [content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded]
* Using Stream ID: 5 (easy handle 0x294a520)
> POST /app/eos/search;jsessionid=hFYDovqSpPQ9unggYELKowMo.21 HTTP/2
Host: apps.irs.gov
accept: */*
cookie: JSESSIONID=hFYDovqSpPQ9unggYELKowMo.21; AWSALBCORS=53A7kbQtYAwW146QYR8asR3SdVn+X7GnECF27cV7LWrC6MEeeAluAo75yZtV6woDy6eJZY0Pn46tZqMMDD2hMlRwaT3Qouuu732Ds2n6s05oILuF4g0yuT1nQOZm; AWSALB=53A7kbQtYAwW146QYR8asR3SdVn+X7GnECF27cV7LWrC6MEeeAluAo75yZtV6woDy6eJZY0Pn46tZqMMDD2hMlRwaT3Qouuu732Ds2n6s05oILuF4g0yuT1nQOZm; ak_bmsc=F7644E5B2E56D5CEC9F9214427EB9974~000000000000000000000000000000~YAAQscM9F2GW4+OAAQAANyj78Q8vLFcckNUD0HpQL3ss6AowiPbRaFmid6iQfoj2VxAeSh/Qr6dNAGezumxbeEwNazFGWBgcYSs6QWeLXTW0IrBS/QWB5ZjpcsMHpVWP7mUH9Vxaq9F6k2JEAN6HyI7aRh1dtaxvNpFmdLGZIVEv0hK8eATTHeNAfTXjz2Gw7c0Ha0BQymd+LD0y7t3NR1wgq0vCu2lWjSYmJ8dLaiW8W3nkeZZxmWKrqQI0OUUKdApQIb1Sag0dsa9qvjfaHcQD2TbrVa76b6Ik7Qk5CQqZDIy/Olo0e45RQylLZXFIxKtWNRN29eM9eNWMcwBdcZ7Q5HgjLMcPEN5WXX8fzYfX4numSMPvDBk+tYS4m3w4rI02HNshjzl4; bm_sz=9B5A183873D9DA7C215F809E880759BE~YAAQscM9F1+W4+OAAQAAsCf78Q/Ng8FzoK+miI/aUvOjaHCHXBGNMhzxx+mfJ8TGPpLyCpaMInVzbUC4GWvCbONhhUqi6fndklKkuuzwADI4kR00c9t1PvQ8V8aA0AKyR8HNfMVMfIs5IuZVdPrw3ZYGDwK5WTykEQgvRafI0xVu/x12vCigOn2+4hMvhJaurXqeBfChnC3RvQiowQy+513BMncaIXgOYsZSuWf4+jgXrAgNEY6Wc2xfBKnHifxycbgVGKgdR+3636bK2wqNRGI4e8WYL+f1ArF48LgMOsQ=~3753527~4404275; _abck=69E0B24E2773CAD514F0180403F5F6A5~-1~YAAQscM9F16W4+OAAQAAsCf78QfvL3BASG5oiS90B4saRsXqnuJNdVzBb/ET/W9XsNJ+6bjHRek2i4SGmzuLG/ZASwyjFYIdCxQiEqOelIFq/N/1jfa9xwgKHPFY7nAgdWuTeawZnlt4ZSOiJiTsRRxNY95vE5cfFzXlQiVigU5E8RYu55DL/fj7t+vLMOKu4DMUtVblmep6xSffeKcxTu1cZqKsrTazZWCJQNimbxOVUuqSvCH3iTgSbuKRY+Z8f9d9tsdOX3UHHfCUoNIIGPVsAAan/c9CPKlaqCbARtLJQJxlci2QmQvz4C1m0q7P7lPO1GIVlwolKYSwOe1EdY/sGHF/tp2N/KmFurCdCK4Jko+kvQTj2lmS~-1~-1~-1
user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/64.0.3282.140 Safari/537.36 Edge/18.17763
accept-language: en-US,en;q=0.5
content-length: 262
content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

* We are completely uploaded and fine
< HTTP/2 403 
< mime-version: 1.0
< content-type: text/html
< content-length: 334
< expires: Mon, 23 May 2022 17:33:30 GMT
< x-reference-error: 18.b1c33d17.1653327210.4d9dfd5
< date: Mon, 23 May 2022 17:33:30 GMT
< strict-transport-security: max-age=31536000
<
```

Comment: The difference is the location from which you access the site. The second example clearly shows a 403 http code being returned, where the first example shows a 302

Comment: It's possible they're blocking your prod system's source IP because they don't like you scraping them. Do they have an API alternative?

Comment: It's a distinct possibility that our IP address is in a range being blocked. Although we are using a Virtual Private Server and don't spam, the address range at HostGator is periodically added to the UCEPROTECTL2 and UCEPROTECTL3 blacklists for a while. There must be some nefarious websites hosted in that group. Thee IRS doesn't seem to have an API for this search.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

The second request lacks the `[84] => 3`, then also `Found bundle for host apps.irs.gov: 0x564a9448dcc0 [can multiplex]`. Please refer to the official documentation; since 2021-12-16 one can download the revocation data [in bulk](https://www.irs.gov/newsroom/irs-makes-tax-exempt-organization-search-primary-source-to-get-exempt-organization-data), eg:
https://www.irs.gov/charities-non-profits/tax-exempt-organization-search-bulk-data-downloads ...or parse the updates they might mail.

Comment: Good catch. 84 is CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, but unfortunately that doesn't affect the 403 response. The implication that it is the IP address at HostGator being rejected is looking like the answer. I deployed my EIN REST end point on an internal server accessible by our website and that works correctly even though the identical code fails when hosted on our website at HostGator.